Do amateurs still search for supernovae?
When I was little, I read Sky and Telescope, and I was always delighted when I saw that an amateur had discovered a supernova.
Now I imagine that even amateurs can do that process automatically. There's probably a public domain program to compare starfield  images. But I don't know if that makes them more or less exciting to find.
I know that there are about half a million supernovae exploding at any one time somewhere inside the Hubble Horizon. I asked about that in an earlier question.
So my question is, given all this, do amateurs still excitedly search for supernovae hoping to get their name in Sky and Telescope?

Yes, and they find them.
The vast majority of supernovae are discovered by automated transient detectors, such as ZTF. But not all. Looking at the data on Rochester astronomy, a source for supernovae data, we can see a list of all supernovae in 2024. And amateurs have discovered some of them!

thank you! 10,000 so far this year, 1 in 100 are amateur.
